# Wiremock isn't intercepting okhttp3 call in junit5

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, junit5, wiremock

When using wiremock to (ty to) intercept and mock calls via okhttp3, it seems that it either doesn't get the call from okhttp or simply makes a passthrough

I followed the basic setup from the [wiremock website](https://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/) and have the following test code:

```kotlin
@WireMockTest
class DummyTest {
    @Test
    fun `Some other test`(wireMockRuntimeInfo: WireMockRuntimeInfo) {
        configureFor("localhost", 8080)
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/dummy/path"))
            .willReturn(ok("test example")))

        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:8080/dummy/path")
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).execute().let {
            val result = it.body()!!.string()

            assertEquals("test example", result)
        }
    }
}
```

My dependendies looks like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    testImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.33.2")
}
```

And the result I get is this:

```
Connect to http://localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at java.base@17.0.4/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.4/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base@17.0.4/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base@17.0.4/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory$1.run(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:87)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:84)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:396)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:158)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
    at app//org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:89)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.safelyExecuteRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:506)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.executeRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:489)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.executeRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:466)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.addStubMapping(HttpAdminClient.java:146)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:414)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:409)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.givenThat(WireMock.java:115)
    at app//com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.java:119)
    at app//DummyTest.Some other test(DummyTest.kt:21)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:201)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

For a complete example see the: [minimal sample project](https://github.com/rohdef/okhttp-wiremock-error)

It occurs to me that it might be some basic instruction missing on their site, however, I have not been able to find any such missing instructions.

How can I proceed from here?